# PythonAnywhere Gitpull Erased Database

Tags: django, database, github, web, pythonanywhere

I recently uploaded my django website to pythonanywhere ([here](https://luckykhoza.pythonanywhere.com/)). I made changes to my code on my local computer and pushed it to Github, then I pull it into my pythonanywhere website.

But when I tried logging into the 'admin' console, I couldn't and all other created user accounts couldn't login. I figured the database was deleted and luckily, I used the create superuser command to regain access, but I lost all the users that previously logged in, and I don't wanna have this issue again.

Any recommendations for how to pull without changing the database?

.....................

Answer (score 0):

If you commit your database to your git repository then, every time you pull, the database will be overwritten by what you have committed in the repository. If you do not want that to happen, do not commit the database in your git repository.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue is I'm trying to figure out how to not commit the database but commit all the other code.